# random string search in google sheet or excel

Tags: regex, excel, string, search, google-sheets

I have an Excel file for different big data. I am cleaning this data and want to remove random strings which end with `C"`

example:

```
hC7cP41nSMkC"
aqlVkmm33-oC"
j3f4tGmQtD8C"
blknAaTinKkC"
```

I want a regular expression to search for any random string ending with `C"` and replace it with empty content using find and replace.

I am open to using Excel or Google Sheets, with or without code to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the 'search using regular expression' box in the find and replace search box in Google Sheets.

Using the regular expression `\S+C"` will replace strings that end in `C"`.

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: there are no entries matching .*[Cc]$

Comment: This was done in Google Sheets with the regular expressions check box ticked? Hmm. I'll think some more.

Comment: yea i wish share with you the screenshot , really appreciate it , its thousands of data and will be hard to clean it manually

Comment: Oh!!!! I didn't realise the quotes were part of the string. I have updated my answer.

Comment: no , there are no formulas at all and even .*[Cc]"$ did not show up also

Comment: Is there a trailing space `xxC" `? Is the string surrounded by any other text inside the cell? Try `\b.*C"\b`.

Comment: Or try `\S+C"`.

Comment: Which expression worked for you? I'll edit my answer. :)